# Why am I getting a 217 error when I call this finalization section?

Tags: delphi

I'm getting a runtime 217 error that I've tracked down to the finalization section of one of my units. This is the code :

```
finalization
begin
  for I:= 0 to CacheList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    tempRecord := CacheList.Items[I];
    for k := 0 to length(tempRecord.details) - 1 do
    begin
      tempRecord.Details[k].free;
    end;
    tempRecord.free;
  end;
  CacheList.Free;
end;
```

and tempRecord is :

```
Record = class
 Details : array of CachedDetails;
 key : string;
end;

CachedDetails = class
 EDate : TDateTime;
 A     : Real;
 B     : Real;
 C     : Real;
end;
```

Even though I get the error, the process does completely successfully. And if I simply comment out the entire finalization the error goes away, but I obviously don't want to leak memory. Am I improperly calling the frees?

Comment: You can't leak memory when your app is exiting. The OS will recover the memory automatically when your process ends. Also, the debugger might tell you where the problem is; what happens when you set a breakpoint on the line starting with `tempRecord :=` and step through the code?

Comment: What type is CacheList? If it is a TList I can't see anything obvious. If you are using D2009 or later, and CacheList is TObjectList<Record>, then I would suspect that OwnsObjects=True and you are attempting to double free the tempRecord. Also, as a matter of style it would be better to get "Record" (which is a strange name for a class) to free the members of the details array.

Comment: That code seems fine. So likely some other code is corrupting this structure. Use the debugger to help.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Instead of "for k := 0 to length(tempRecord.details) - 1 do" you should use "for k := low(tempRecord.details) to high(tempRecord.details) do".

Comment: Another thing: The free'ing of the Details array should be in the destructor of the tempRecord class, and not be the responsibility of the consumer of the class. Maybe it already is? If so, that would mean that the array is being attempted free'd twice.

Comment: @HeartWare Those `for` loops are identical.

Comment: One crucial piece of missing information: what is the type of `CacheList`?

Comment: @David: The for loops are only identical IN THIS INSTANCE because the array is a dynamic array. If the array for some reason was changed to "array[10..20] of CachedDetails;" then the first for loop would crash the program, whereas the second one would process the entire array, as was most likely the intent of the code. Therefore, it is always a good practice to use LOW and HIGH when processing arrays, as they are oblivious to the actual underlying dimensional range of the array.

Comment: @HeartWare Right. I wanted to make it clear that your comment was not meant to help solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good advice to Free Items of a List, while they belong to the list.
You have to check if it is a kind of TObjectList and if this List owns the objects.

Or you Extract the Item from List and free it.

```
finalization
begin
  while CacheList.Count > 0 do
  begin
    tempRecord := CacheList.Extract( CacheList.First );
    for k := 0 to length(tempRecord.details) - 1 do
    begin
      tempRecord.Details[k].free;
    end;
    tempRecord.free;
  end;
  CacheList.Free;
end;
```

But just as a think it over, if you hand over the destroy responsibility to the Record class and CacheList a TObjectList with OwnsObjects=True then your finlization code will look like this

```
finalization

CacheList.Free;
```